# One View as StatusView in all ViewControler

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiview

i have a small view under my navigation bar with information. I would like to see this same information view in my another three viewcontroller when i switch to them. Do I need to create each time a new View?

Many Thanks!

**UPDATE**: THE SOLUTION IS [self.navigationController.view insertSubview:pullDownView atIndex:1]; see the post below

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have defined `UINavigationController` or any container controller which load very first time in `AppDelegate` or elsewhere, at that time programmatically add your view as a subview of navigationcontoller.view or in your container controller under navigation bar. Here you have to make sure about the perfect position of your subview.

Comment: i didnt defined it directly. the methods in appdelegate are empty. I only use a storyboard with a navigationcontroller. it is possible? how can i do it?

Comment: Using storyboard, you can't add view into navigation controller. You have to add programmatically.

Comment: i add my view to the navigationController with this code [self.navigationController.view addSubview:pullDownView]; ... that is perfect! 

The problem is now the view i add covers the navigationbar. I need the navigationbar.

Comment: now i have a solution. The navigation bar is now visible. The custom view i add to the navigationcontroller.view is visible but below the navigationbar. 

this is the code vor adding a custom view

[self.navigationController.view insertSubview:customView atIndex:1];

Answer (score 1):

No need to add view in every controller.we can customise on wanted controllers.Just add the view as subview to the window.Try this solution it may help for you.
//In appDelegate.h

```
@property (strong,nonatomic) UIView *bottomView;
```

//In appDelegate.m

```
    - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    _bottomView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 65, 320, 50)];
        _bottomView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
        _bottomView.hidden = YES;
 [self.window addSubview:_bottomView];
    }
```

//In viewcontroller1.m

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
    - (void)viewDidLoad {
        [super viewDidLoad];    
        AppDelegate *aDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
        aDelegate.bottomView.hidden = NO;    
    }
```

//In viewcontroller2.m

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
    - (void)viewDidLoad {
        [super viewDidLoad];    
        AppDelegate *aDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
        aDelegate.bottomView.hidden = NO;    
    }
```

//In viewcontroller3.m

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
    - (void)viewDidLoad {
        [super viewDidLoad];    
        AppDelegate *aDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
        aDelegate.bottomView.hidden = NO;    
    }
```

//In other viewcontrollers

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
        - (void)viewDidLoad {
            [super viewDidLoad];    
            AppDelegate *aDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
            aDelegate.bottomView.hidden = YES;    
        }
```

Comment: When i change your code to _bottomView.hidden = NO in appdelegate i cant see anything. Then i add this ( [self.window makeKeyAndVisible]) to app deleagate... but then i see the buttomView over all elements(navigationbar too)

Answer (score 0):

No, add the view as a subview to your window, and make sure you position it correctly. Test your code with events that change the window dimensions (switching from a call to the app, for example).

If you are using a navigation controller or any other view controller container, it might be better to add your view as a subview in the container, though I have not personally tried this myself and it may not work or involve too many hacks/work arounds to properly work.

Answer (score 0):

You can make an extension of UIViewController. that extension class will have function to add the view on top.

So in whichever view you want to add Subview on top, you will just have to call that function.

Please refer below link to see how to create category extension,
http://iosdevelopertips.com/objective-c/categories.html

you can create same for UIViewcontroller.

Comment: have all views in the viewcntroller also the same datasource?

Comment: @NoBody: No, If you are talking about info label in view then you can pass string parameter or any other data in function while adding on viewcontroller.